# regex grabbing too much info

Tags: python, regex

My script:

```
def fetch_online():
    pattern = re.search('(<span class="on">)(.*)(</span>)', data)
    return pattern.group(2)

print fetch_online()
```

Inside `data`, there is one line that contains this:

```
        <b><span><span class="on">5879</span> users online</span></b>
```

However, when ran, the output is this:

```
5879</span> users online
```

How should I fix this so it only grabs the data before the first `</span>`?

Comment: Repeat after me: [Do not try to parse HTML with Regular Expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/100297)!

Comment: Depending on the scope of your project, [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) is a pretty good Python library for handling HTML.

Comment: `soup.findAll('span', {'class': 'on'})[0].text`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your specific case here, got for `<span class="on">)(\d+)</span>`. In a more general approach, go for non-greedy:

```
<span class="on">(.*?)</span>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the non-greedy quantifier: `(<span class="on">)(.*?)(</span>)`.

To learn more about the non-greedy quantifier, read the "Laziness Instead of Greediness" section at [Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html).

Just to reiterate what has already been said in the comments, [parsing HTML using regular expressions is highly discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).